# Answer is only printing .0 instead of .00 in python

Tags: python

> Please help me print my answer as ".00". I have tried using the round function but it doesn't work.

```
#Here is my code    
print("VAT amount: R", round(vat_calc(item_price),2))
```

[In the picture it shows what I receive while using the round function. I would like it to show ".00" at the VAT amount.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Gmj.png)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Comment: try using c like format for printing  print("%.2f" % round(vat_calc(item_price),2))

Comment: @ikibir: I tried doing this:

Comment: @ikibir: print("VAT amount: R", end="")
    print("%.2f" % round(vat_calc(item_price),2)) ... but it didnt work. It still only prints ".0"

Comment: @Anonymous print("%.2f" % round(0,2)) this works for me what is yout python version

Comment: @ikibir I,m using python version 3.8

Comment: @ikibir Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it. Everything works perfectly.